# Real Analysis Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Real analysis question about differentiation

Assume that $f$ and $f'$  are differentiable on $\mathbf R$ and that for every x in $\mathbf R$,  $f(x) + f''(x) = 0 $. Show that $g (x)= f^2(x) + (f'(x))^2$ is a constant.

Comment: Differentiate $g$ with respect to $x$ and factorize.

Comment: Please don't link pictures, but write it directily here using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please share your thoughts about the problem and let us know where you are stuck. Posting just problem statements is discouraged here.

Comment: I really don't understand which to prove first, in order to prove g(x) is constant, g'(x) must be equals to zero for all x in the intervals, and I've tried to prove the f(x)+f''(x)=0 using the Rolle's theorem and now I'm confused  @ParamanandSingh

Comment: sorry, my mistake @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Did you try to differentiate $g$? What is your expression for $g'(x) $ given $g(x) =(f(x)) ^2+(f'(x))^2$?

Comment: Please compare your working with the solution offered by @DavidC.Ullrich and figure our what mistake you made at your end. The problem is neither trivial nor difficult and very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $f+f''=0$.

> > Then $g=f^2+(f')^2$ is constant.

Proof: $g'=2ff'+2f''f'=2f'(f+f'')=0$.

It's amusing to note that this proves uniqueness for the solution:

> > **Cor.** If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then $f=0$.

And hence

> > **Cor.** If $f''+f=0$, $f(0)=a$ and $f'(0)=b$ then $f(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$.

Proof: The previous corollary shows that $g=0$, if $g(x)=f(x)-(a\cos(x)+b\sin(x))$.

Comment: thank you very much! now I realized I miss interpreted the question

Comment: @AnonAnon It's traditional for you to "accept" the answer by clicking on that arrow...

Answer (score -1):

Solution of ode $f+f''=0$ is $f=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x$. Then
$$f^2+f'^2=c_1^2+c_2^2$$